# stylelint ignore rule for specific folder/file

Tags: css, stylelint

I looked at stylelint's docs and only saw a way to disable stylelint for running on for specific files/directories but what I really want is a way to disable specific rules) for specific files/directories. Is there a way to achieve that? I don't want to use `stylelint-disable` within the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In the future](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/3128), you'll be able to use the `overrides` configuration property. In the meantime, you can work around this missing feature by using the [`extend` configuration property](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#extends) and by running stylelint twice.

Create a second config that extends the more limited main config and turns on additional rules:

`.extended-stylelintrc.json`:

```js
{
    extends: "./.stylelintrc.json",
    rules: {
        "unit-whitelist": ["px"]
    }
};
```

Or you can create a second config that extends a full main config and turns off rules:

`.limited-stylelintrc.json`:

```js
{
    extends: "./.stylelintrc.json",
    rules: {
        "property-no-unknown": null
    }
};
```

It will require two npm tasks to run it, though:

```sh
stylelint "**/*.css"
stylelint "special/**/*.css" --config .extended-stylelintrc.js
```

Or it can be combined into one:

```sh
stylelint "**/*.css" && stylelint "special/**/*.css" --config .extended-stylelintrc.js
```

Comment: Seems clunky, but I guess I'll take that

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you can not use the [`ignoreFiles` option](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#ignorefiles)
or `.stylelintignore`?

> #### `ignoreFiles`
>
> You can provide a glob or array of globs to ignore specific files.
>
> For example, you can ignore all JavaScript files:
>
> ```
> {
>   "ignoreFiles": ["**/*.js"]
> }
> ```

Comment: This ignores all rules for those files. I only want to ignore some rules for those files